# React-router Uncaught TypeError: type.toUpperCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, browserify, react-router

I'm using the latest version of react, react-router, gulp and browserify 
I got this in beowser console:
Uncaught TypeError: type.toUpperCase is not a function

my code in app.js:

```
"use strict";
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Header = require('./components/Header');
var Index = require('./components/Index');
var About = require('./components/About')
var Route = Router.Route;
var IndexRoute  = Router.IndexRoute ;


var App = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
})
React.render(<Router><Route path="/" component={App}>
<IndexRoute  component={Index}/>
<Route path="about" component={About}/>
</Route>
</Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Can you show the actual code that produces the error? None of this code would directly cause that error.

Comment: It's all about react-router and the <Router> component, because when I remove the <Router> component from React.render function and replace it with any other component like <Header /> the code works fine.

Comment: Again, I would have to see the actual code throwing the error to tell you anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade your react router version from 0.0.13 to 1.0.0-rc1(beta) coz the below code will only work for 1.0.0 beta version which is mentioned in [change log](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md).

```
React.render(<Router><Route path="/" component={App}>
<IndexRoute  component={Index}/>
<Route path="about" component={About}/>
</Route>
</Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

After upgrading version you have to declare router properly like below.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter .Router;
var Route = ReactRouter .Route;
```

Now router is defined properly. This worked for me..give a try.